# Xcode 13 build an interactive tutorial

Tags: swift, xcode13, docc

I have an app which is a little complicated to figure out details without a help document. I don't want to host the help document only on a web server for users who might not prefer to leave the app and go through the tutorial on a web page. So my question is: Is it possible to make use of DocC tutorial and present the tutorial to my users in the app without leaving the app? Is not, the only solution would be to provide a link for my users to open the web page in Safari I guess. My second question is: Is it possible to host DocC tutorial on an Amazon S3 bucket?

Comment: Yes, using a web view

Comment: Would you consider adding an interactive tutorial instead of a help document? When the user first installs the application, you can detect it with userDefaults and open the tutorial screen.

Comment: @EzgiÖzkan That is one of the options being considered right now, thank you.